# Import information from a web URL that requires a username and password

Tags: import, web-access

I wish to use:

```
Import[link, "Plaintext"]
```

to get the plain text on a web page - however the webpage is on an internal network and requires a username and password for access.

I have tried using:

```
URLFetch[link, "Content", "Username" -> "myusername",  "Password" -> "mypassword"]
```

and then execute my Import line, but this will not work. Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: I am not near a computer but you will need to save the cookie with your login info. There may be examples in the docs

Comment: Also take a look at how the login information is send by inspecting the headers: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/http-headers-for-dummies--net-8039 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423061/view-http-headers-in-google-chrome

Answer (score 5):

I managed to figure out what I needed!

Indeed, the answer that worked for me is to pass along the cookie information that contains the login information for the site. Once I pinpointed which cookie was needed (I personally found this information with my Chrome browser in Advanced Settings, under “Privacy and Security” -> "Content Settings” -> “Cookies”), I used Mathematica's SetCookie function. Prior to executing the Import line, I ran something like this:

```
SetCookies[<|"Domain" -> "[INSERT_VALUE]", "Path" -> "[INSERT_VALUE]", "Name" -> "[INSERT_VALUE]",  "Content" -> "[INSERT_VALUE]"|>];
```

I replaced all “[INSERT_VALUE]" with the appropriate information about the cookie.

I then executed my

```
Import[link, "Plaintext"]
```

line, and voila! I have the information I needed!

Comment: If you are using `URLRead` instead of `URLFetch`, is the cookie correctly set automatically? (see [`CookieFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CookieFunction.html))